# can't get full date value from li jquery

Tags: jquery

This seems weird but i can't get the full date value from a li
https://jsfiddle.net/hgo7L41z/1/

```js
$("li").click(function () {       
    var a = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pageno">
    <li value="11/8/2018">1</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">2</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">3</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">4</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">5</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">6</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">7</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">8</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">9</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">10</li>
</ul>
```

can you help please, thanks.

Comment: try `$(this).val()` instead of  `$(this).attr('value)`

Comment: If you change attribute name to "attr-value" then it's ok on jsFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data attributes to achieve this

```js
$("li").click(function () {       
    var a = $(this).data('value');
    console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pageno">
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">1</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">2</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">3</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">4</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">5</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">6</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">7</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">8</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">9</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch yeah that was my problem, but since I can't upgrade the version of jquery for now I will use data-value

Answer (score 1):

That fiddle uses a quite old jQuery version (1.3.2) - maybe that's the cause, since here in the snippet (version 3.3.1) it works (I changed the dates to get different values):

```js
$("li").click(function ()
{       
var a = $(this).attr('value');

console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pageno">
    <li value="11/1/2018">1</li>
    <li value="11/2/2018">2</li>
    <li value="11/3/2018">3</li>
    <li value="11/4/2018">4</li>
    <li value="11/5/2018">5</li>
    <li value="11/6/2018">6</li>
    <li value="11/7/2018">7</li>
    <li value="11/8/2018">8</li>
    <li value="11/9/2018">9</li>
    <li value="11/10/2018">10</li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Good catch.  A version from *11 years ago* is downright ancient, and probably wouldn't even support my suggestion above to use `data-*` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
<li value="11/8/2018">1</li>
```

Use

```
<li data-value="11/8/2018">1</li>
```

And

```
$("li").click(function () {       
    var a = $(this).attr('data-value');
    console.log(a);
});
```

```js
$("li").click(function ()
{       
var a = $(this).attr('data-value');

console.log(a);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pageno">
    <li data-value="11/1/2018">1</li>
    <li data-value="11/2/2018">2</li>
    <li data-value="11/3/2018">3</li>
    <li data-value="11/4/2018">4</li>
    <li data-value="11/5/2018">5</li>
    <li data-value="11/6/2018">6</li>
    <li data-value="11/7/2018">7</li>
    <li data-value="11/8/2018">8</li>
    <li data-value="11/9/2018">9</li>
    <li data-value="11/10/2018">10</li>

    </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you Rob i will use data-value